# CodeIgniter - Monthly Archives

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to develop a simple list of monthly archives for my site's blog. I have pulled the records from the database, and now I just need to sort them accordingly so they appear in this way:

```
<h4>February '12</h4>

<ul>
    <li>Article 1</li>
    <li>Article 1</li>
    <li>Article 1</li>
</ul>

<h4>January '12</h4>

<ul>
    <li>Article 1</li>
    <li>Article 1</li>
    <li>Article 1</li>
</ul>
```

And so on.

Here is the function from my controller that pulls the records:

```
public function get_archives()

{

    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT id, 
        title, 
        date_published 
        FROM blog_post 
        ORDER BY date_published DESC
    ");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)

    {

        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

And I have then passed those results to my view using $archives. The date_published value returns a timestamp of for example 2012-01-13 18:39:53.

What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already got them sorted in an chronological order, you could just traverse them in a loop and print the heading every time the year-month part of the date changes.

Example:

```
// get list of blog-items
$archives = $this->get_archives();

$last_year_month = "";

// traverse items in foreach loop
foreach($archives as $d) {
  // extract year and month
  $year_month = substr($d["date_published"], 0, 7);

  // if year and month has changed
  if ($year_month != $last_year_month) {
    // if not the first heading, close previous UL
    if ($last_year_month != "") echo "</ul>\n";

    $last_year_month = $year_month;

    echo "<h4>" . date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, intval(substr($year_month, 5, 2)) - 1, 1, 1970)) . " " . substr($year_month, 2, 2) . "</h4>\n";

    // opening UL for next list
    echo "<ul>\n";
  }

  echo "  <li>" . $d["title"] . "</li>\n";
}
// only print if an UL was opened
if ($last_year_month != "") echo "</ul>\n";
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! One last question though. How can I convert for example 2012-02 into February '12?

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly. (Please test it if it works.)

Comment: Very, very close. I had to tweak one line slightly. echo "<h4>" . date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, intval(substr($year_month, 5, 2)) - 1, 1, 1970)) . " " . "'" . substr($year_month, 2, 2) . "</h4>";

Thanks so much for your help. You are a godsend!